# php ignores if for $_SESSION['variable']

Tags: php, session, if-statement

I'm having a strange problem with $_SESSION.

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['passed']))
  {
     echo "passed";
     unset $_SESSION['passed']; 
  }
  else
  {
  echo "not passed";
  }
```

as a result i get "not passed",but when i comment "unset $_SESSION['passed'];"
i get passed.My intention was just to delete 'passed',so that you can't call the document again by typing in the url. i guess it has to do with the server options but i have no idea which one it could be. has anyone an idea why php bevaves this way?

Edit: i use xampp

edit2:

sorry,it works when i have it that way:

set_pass.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['passed']="123";
header('location:check.php');
?>
```

check.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['passed']))
{
echo "passed";
unset($_SESSION['passed']);
}
else 
{
echo "not passed";
}
?>
```

but not in my project,where all comes from an index.php and the "check.php" shows that an session already had started.

**EDIT 3**

okay to get closer to the problem i rebuilt my mvc system without view/model and controler is in index.php:

index.php

```
<?php
include 'load.php';

$view =  (isset($_POST['view'])) ? $_POST['view'] : 'default';
echo "<br><b>".$view."</b><br";

$do = new load();

switch($view)

{
     case 'default':
     echo $do->_load('captcha.php');
     break;

     case 'setpass':
     echo $do->_load('setpass.php');
     break;
}

?>
```

load.php

```
<?php
class load
{

   public function _load($string)
   {
   ob_start();

   include $string;

   $output = ob_get_contents();

   ob_end_clean();

   return $output;
}

}
?>
```

captcha.php

```
 <form action="?view=setpass" method="post">
 <img id="captcha" src="securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="CAPTCHA Image">
 <input type="text" name="captcha_code" size="10" maxlength="6">
 <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha').src =    'securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[ Different Image ]</a>
 <input type="submit" value="GO">
 </form>
```

setpass.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'securimage/securimage.php';
$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['captcha_code']) == false) 
{
echo "The security code entered was incorrect.<br /><br />";
echo "Please go <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>back</a> and try again.";
exit;
}

else
{
$_SESSION['passed']="123";
header('location:check.php');
}


?>
```

and at last:check.php(same as above)

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['passed']))
{
echo "passed";
unset($_SESSION['passed']);
}
else 
{
echo "not passed";
}
?>
```

**the problem is now,when you click on the "Go submit-button" in captcha.php,nothing happens. you even get not a post or a get(i tried everything with foreach($POST)..**

I have just no explanation for this phenomenon but i'm beginner,so maybe you know what it is?!

Comment: Do you have `session_start()` at the top of the page?

Comment: `unset($_SESSION['passed']);`

Comment: PHP just does what you write. You're telling to unset if it exists. If you stop and think about it, it's code smell for what you try to accomplish : "you can't call the document again".

Answer (score 0):

Add session_start(); in your index.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry in my MVC was a line which includes the templates twice,but it
wasn't shown on the output.